# How to catch the standard video output in Java

Tags: java, coordinates, screenshot, video-capture, monitor

I want to catch the system's standard output, that is all that we can see at the monitor, from `0,0` coordinates to `x,y`. I've tried to make `50` screen capture per second with the `Robot.createScreenCapture(Rectangle rectangle))` method, but it use a lot of memory and CPU. Instead, If I could catch the standard output and reproduce it in a video player (for example) I think that it should use less memory and cpu. Can anyone point me in the direction?

Answer (score 0):

Recording the screen is a very OS environment specific task. On Linux one would, for example, do screen capture by talking to the X server directly using XLib or similar library.

If you are lucky someone has created a library in Java which abstracts this work (Like the Robot class), but if you can't find such a library then you will have to do the implementation for each platform yourself.

Unfortunately you would probably have to do some work in another language than Java since there might not exist Java bindings for the OS specific calls that you would have to make.

A good starting point would be to look at an existing project. For Linux this could be RecordMyDesktop:
http://recordmydesktop.sourceforge.net/development.php

For Windows you could look at: http://taksi.sourceforge.net/

So to sum things up: Java might not be right "hammer" for the task in question.